# SDL_UpperBlit: passed a NULL surface error

Tags: c++, sdl

In the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SDL.h"
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    SDL_Surface*  screenSurface = nullptr;
    SDL_Surface* image = nullptr;
    SDL_Window* window = nullptr;

    const Uint8* keystate;

    SDL_Rect offset;
    offset.x = 100;
    offset.y = 200;

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
    {
        cout << "Window initialization error: " << SDL_GetError();
    }
    else
    {
        window = SDL_CreateWindow("game", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

        bool isRunning = true;
        SDL_Event ev;

        //game loop
        while (isRunning)
        {
            while (SDL_PollEvent(&ev) != 0)
            {
                if (ev.type == SDL_QUIT)
                    isRunning = false;
            }

            keystate = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);
            if (keystate[SDL_SCANCODE_W])
            {
                offset.y -= 1;
            }
            else if (keystate[SDL_SCANCODE_A])
            {
                offset.x -= 1;
            }
            else if (keystate[SDL_SCANCODE_S])
            {
                offset.y += 1;
            }
            else if (keystate[SDL_SCANCODE_D])
            {
                offset.x += 1;
            }

            screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
            image = SDL_LoadBMP("world.bmp");
            SDL_BlitSurface(image, NULL, screenSurface, &offset);
            SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
            cout << SDL_GetError() << endl;
        }
    }

    SDL_FreeSurface(image);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

    image = nullptr;
    window = nullptr;
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;

}
```

I get an error, saying: "SDL_UpperBlit: passed a NULL surface error."  But the error did not occur until I went from using a switch statement in the while loop for SDL_PollEvent, to just using if statements using SDL_SCANCODE_ in the isRunning while loop. So the error does not occur instantly, but after a short while, like 10 seconds or so. So I am able to move around the world.bmp with WASD for a short while, then I get the error "SDL_UpperBlit: passed a NULL surface error.".

What's the solution for this?

Comment: You're loading image on each frame, but freeing it only once on exit. Most likely you're running out of available memory and `SDL_LoadBMP` eventually returns NULL.

Answer (score 1):

```
image = SDL_LoadBMP("world.bmp");
```

This loads `world.bmp` from the disk, creates a brand new surface and stores the image inside. You never destroy this surface, and you don't check for errors either.

As you're running this once per frame, SDL quickly runs out of resources, `SDL_LoadBMP` returns `NULL` to signal it, and you pass that `NULL` to `SDL_BlitSurface`.

Only load your resources once, and take care of destroying them at the right time. C++ has smart pointers and RAII to do that for you.

Comment: Thanks, I added `SDL_FreeSurface(image);` to the isRunning loop, which fixed it. Though at closure of the program I get an exception thrown, whichn in turn doesn't close the window properly. Any suggestion for that?

Comment: @ye546 you should probably move the `SDL_LoadBMP` outside of the loop instead. Unless you intend on replacing the `world.bmp` file sixty times a second and have the program keep up.

Comment: Just me being silly, I forgot to add `SDL_FreeSurface(screenSurface);`

Comment: @ye546 [documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowSurface) explicitly says not to.